# Unable to create AxisService from ServiceEndpointAddress

Tags: service, axis

I do some testing on WS. I create a wsdl with multiple method.

But I only can execute the 1st method, others failed and give me error below:

```
javax.xml.ws.ProtocolException: CWWSS7200E: Unable to create AxisService from ServiceEndpointAddress 
atorg.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createProtocolException(ExceptionFactory.java:199)
atorg.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeProtocolException(ExceptionFactory.java:97)
atorg.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1256)
atorg.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:975)
atorg.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitBareMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitBareMethodMarshaller.java:412)
atorg.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.getFaultResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:421)
atorg.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:384)
atorg.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:308)
atorg.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:158)
    at $Proxy28.deleteContainer(Unknown Source)
atcom.privasia.etp.ldoprocess.service.DeleteContainerProcessPortProxy.deleteContainer(DeleteContainerProcessPortProxy.java:83)
    at DeleteContainerTest.main(DeleteContainerTest.java:48)
```

Any Idea what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebSphere then it is due to a bug in WebSphere. 
refer...

[PK96567: CWWSS7200E: UNABLE TO CREATE AXISSERVICE FROM SERVICEENDPOINTADD RESS WHEN CONTEXT ROOT IS "/"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK96567)

> Local fix
>
> ```
> Not using "/" for context root.
> ```
>
> Problem summary
>
> ```
> ****************************************************************
> * USERS AFFECTED:  IBM WebSphere Application Server V7.0 users *
> *                  of JAX-WS web services                      *
> ****************************************************************
> * PROBLEM DESCRIPTION: When a JAX-WS web service is deployed   *
> *                      using "/" as context root, a client     *
> *                      cannot access the web service.          *
> ****************************************************************
> * RECOMMENDATION:                                              *
> ****************************************************************
> When a JAX-WS web service is deployed using "/" as the context
> root, the web services runtime doesn't parse the request URL
> correctly.
>
> The result is that the client cannot access the web
> service.
>
> The following exception may occur in the ffdc log:
>
> CWWSS7200E:
> Unable to create AxisService from ServiceEndpointAddress
> at
> com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.core.SoapSecurityException.format(SoapS
> ecurityException.java:100)
> at
> com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.util.Axis2Util.isServiceProvider(Axis2Util
> .java:109)
> at
> com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.handler.WSSecurityConsumerHandler._invoke(
> WSSecurityConsumerHandler.java:231)
> ```